# Create a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a 2D array that ranges for 1 to 70 years and 1-12 for each year. For example using some kind of for loop to get this below:

EDTI:
index = (1,1),(1,2),(1,3)....(1,12), (2,1)...(2,12),(3,1)...(3,12).....(70,12)

and then create a multi-index dataframe.

I want the result of the code below to be in array format that I can set as multi-index.

```
for j in range(1,71):
    for i in range(1,13)
        print(j,i)
```

apologies for the bad/vague original question

Comment: `array = [ [ 0 for i in range(12) ] for j in range(70) ]`

Comment: `0 for i ...` or `i for i .....` ? @GerardoZinno

Comment: use i instead of 0 if you want the array to be filled with values in the range, also replace `range(12)` with `range(1, 13)`.

Comment: @GerardoZinno I am not the OP, I just thought you might've done a typo. For the OP, use `array = [[ i for i in range(1, 13)] for j in range(1, 71)]`

Comment: @muyustan sorry, I was distracted.

Comment: Can you check out my recent update to the question? I added better clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[i for i in range(1, 13)] for j in range(1, 71)]
```

This code uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).